# How to observe typing change in UITextField using RxSwift?

Tags: swift, validation, uitextfield, rx-swift

I'm trying to validate text and merge it with UITextField typing event. Here is validation sequence:

```
let validation = textField.rx.text.map {ValidationService.validate($0)}
```

I tested all combining methods but without result:

```
Observable.zip(textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged), validation)

// Select
// No event

// Typing: "A"
// zip failed(message: "Field cannot be empty") () <- wrong

// Typing: "Aa"
// zip failed(message: "Field cannot be empty") () <- wrong

// Typing: "Aaa"
// zip failed(message: "Email is wrong") () <- correct

// UnSelect
// No event

Observable.combineLatest(textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged), validation)

// Select
// No event

// Typing: "A"
// combineLatest combineLatest failed(message: "Email is wrong") () <- correct

// Typing: "Aa"
// combineLatest failed(message: "Field cannot be empty") () <- correct
// combineLatest failed(message: "Field cannot be empty") () <- correct

// UnSelect
// combineLatest failed(message: "Email is wrong") () <- wrong

validation
.withLatestFrom(textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged))

// Select
// No event

// Typing: "A"
// No event

// Typing: "Aa"
// withLatestFrom () failed(message: "Email is wrong") <- correct

// UnSelect
// withLatestFrom () failed(message: "Email is wrong") <- wrong
```

Do you know any other approach to solve my problem?

Comment: You need to `.subscribe` for there to be any result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your viewDidLoad():

```
textField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map { $0.isValidEmail }
    .subscribe(onNext: { isValid in
        print("email is \(isValid ? "" : "Not") Valid")
    })
```

The above uses this extension:

```
extension String {
    var isValidEmail: Bool {
        let emailRegex = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex)
        return  predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```